# Decrease loading time large query with images

Tags: mysql, image

I have a table on my website which gives the visitor an overview of many football players including their photo, club and nation image. It loads these players from a database which has 14000 of them and shows only 30 players per page. Now the problem is, it takes too long to load these players and their 3 images. I already tried Lazyloader which took away some of the loading time but not enough.

Do you have any tips how I can decrease the loading time of my page?

Edit* Link to page loading stats: http://nl.tinypic.com/r/x51hl0/8

It seems that the request loading time causes 76% (over 1 sec.) of the loading time. How do I decrease this?

Comment: by saying "too long" how much time do you mean? have you checked in the network tab of your debugger to see what is slowing the page load?

Comment: Too long like 1.5 sec. where I would like to get the page loaded in a blink of eye ;)

Comment: You need to provide more information. Please paste your database structure and some sample data into a tool like sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/

It is particularly important for us to see how you are handling images. Do you store them directly in the table, or simply reference their location in the file structure (which is often faster).

Comment: This is hard because I have 86 colums per record so it would take a long time to paste tis in sqlfiddle. But I can tell you that the images in the table only contain the url of the images which refers to an external source.

Comment: can you tell how many connections are being made from client to the server to load the page?(including html and all js, css and images). or even can you tell this lag which bothers you is cause by the server to prepare the page for you or this time take fro the page load? you can add a piece of code to your server-side script to check how much time it takes to run

Comment: @EhsanT I make only 6 connections total on the page. It's cuased by the page load it think because it used microtime() on my page and it's 1.3sec.

Comment: I edited the post! Maybe that will help you